# Uncaught exception when passing segue in Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, sigabrt

The function `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` crashes with uncaught exception and leads to `class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate{` with Thread1: signal SIGABRT error

This is wrong issuance of delegates I suppose. Any ideas as to how this can be handled?

```
import UIKit

class UnitTableViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UIActionSheetDelegate {
    let cellID = "cellID"

    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self
    }

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 2
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellID) as UITableViewCell!
        if !(cell != nil){
            cell = UITableViewCell(style:.Default, reuseIdentifier: cellID)
        }
        if indexPath.row == 0
        {
            cell.textLabel?.text = "2016"
        }
        else {
            cell.textLabel?.text = "2017"
        }

        return cell;
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return String (format: "Please select year of study", section + 1)
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForFooterInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return String (format: "Thankyou for your selection", section + 1)
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        switch (indexPath.row) {
        case 0:
            [self.performSegueWithIdentifier("2015Segue'", sender: self)]
        case 1:
            [self.performSegueWithIdentifier("2016Segue'", sender: self)]
        default:
            break;
        }
       // NSLog("Row %ld selected on Section %ld", indexPath.row + 1, indexPath.section + 1)
        tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have segues named `2015Segue'` and `2016Segue'` in your storyboard?

Comment: Why do you have square brackets `[ ]` around `self.performSegueWithIdentifer`?

Comment: Please see http://www.raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1 to learn how to debug a crash.

Comment: Post your crash crash Log here

Comment: yes i have segues 2015Segue and 2016Segue connected.

Comment: it still performs the same error without the brackets [ ]

Comment: remove `[ ]` from `self.performSegueWithIdentifer`

Comment: Did you use "cellID" as your cell ID in storyboard?

Comment: Show your `CrashLog`. I will help you to fix this